# How to write good C++ when interacting with low(er) level interfaces?

Tags: c++

In my C++ code I have to deal with interfaces written in C as well as with CUDA kernels. I posted some questions here on Stackoverflow how to do this or that in C++. I got a lot of answers like: "Don't do it like that. There are better solutions in C++, have a look at this or that." On the other hand, I think that I really *had* to do it in that way because of the interaction with the C interfaces or CUDA.

Long story short: I realize more and more that C interfaces and low level stuff lead to difficulties when designing code in a good C++ philosophy.

What do I want now? I'm looking for some literature like "Effective C++" but specifically for people who have to deal with low level aspects.

Comment: You nearly always end up creating function stubs in some form or other: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub

Comment: I'm confused...are you trying to make your interface c/CUDA callable, or are you trying to make object oriented wrappers around c/CUDA code?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer with an actual example.

Comment: I see the problem. It's not a question on how to solve a specific problem. I'm more looking for some literature like "Effective C++" but specifically for people who have to deal with low level aspects.

Comment: You use every problem's solution #1: add a level of indirection.

Comment: Take a look at API Design for C++ http://www.apibook.com/blog/ as I found it helpful though I do not remember anything about CUDA.  It does discuss C and C++ APIs.

Comment: I got recommended another book: Real-Time C++ Efficient Object-Oriented and Template Microcontroller Programming by Chris Kormanyos. Seems to be more or less what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are some concepts you want to keep in mind as you *architect* and *design* your code:

- Encapsulation / Data Hiding
- Propagation of Change
- Details / Abstraction
- Coupling / Dependencies

The common architecture is to use a pyramid layout for abstraction.  The bottom most layer knows the specifics of the hardware.  Each layer upward is an abstraction away from the hardware towards the application.

### Encapsulation & Data Hiding

The idea here is that every thing related to a single hardware item should be in its encapsulation.  Common devices that share same functionality except they are placed at different addresses, should inherit from a single interface.

For example, given 3 USB ports at addresses 0x1000, 0x2000, and 0x3000, all be have the same way.  The only difference is that their hardware registers are at different addresses.  So, there should be a USB_Interface_Base_Class, and either 3 instances or 3 child classes.

The USB class(es) should only expose fundamental functionality.  The User of the classes doesn't care about the hardware registers, only about performing I/O.  Thus the details are hidden from external users of the class.

### Propagation Of Change

During Research and Development, the hardware is volatile and can change.  It may also change during production.  The objective is to reduce the propagation of change.  For example, if the USB interface is changed to Wireless, the hardware access layer should change, but the change should not propagate deep into the application.  The fewer modules that require change, the better.

### Details & Abstraction

Each layer away from the hardware should be at a higher level of abstraction than the previous, lower layer.

For example, the highest abstraction performs: `cout << "Hello\n";
The next layer down may buffer the data and call a "driver".
The driver says it wants to talk to a character output device. The default character device is connected to USB.
The USB driver talks to the hardware interface to set up registers and transmit the data.

At the highest level, the User wants to output text to the default output port, which is the abstraction.  The layers below fill in the details to get the job done.

### Coupling / Dependencies

The dependency between two or modules is *coupling*.  There is a degree of coupling from tight to loose.  Two modules are considered tightly coupled when an internal change to one module requires changed to the other.  Two modules are loosely coupled when an internal change to one module doesn't affect the other module.

The goal of loose coupling is to help reduce the propagation of change throughout the system.  If one module accesses the data members of another and the data members change, the calling module needs to change.  If the calling module uses an interface, then the provider can change its data members without any affect to the calling module.  The propagation of change has stopped.

### Summary

There's more to accessing hardware than coding.  The principles of Encapsulation, Propagation of Change, Abstraction and Coupling should be considered first.  The code accessing the hardware should follow the principles.  A good process is to architect and design with the principles in mind before coding.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But isn't it a bit too general for the asked question? ;-) But thanks anyway!

Comment: If you like the answer or it helped you, click on the check mark.